# mochi games integration problem

Tags: javascript, flash, mochi

We send below code of request according to the instruction of mochi games client:

```
var options = {partnerID: "xxxxxxxx", id: "idx"};
options.userID = 1;
options.username = 'username';
options.gateway = 'http://example.com/game';
options.width = 320;
options.height = 300;
options.debug = true;
Mochi.addLeaderboardIntegration(options);
```

There is no reaction from flash. Has anybody had successful experience of integration with mochi games? Please help.

Here is the instruction: http://www.mochimedia.com/support/pub_docs#boards

Comment: Will be useful to provide some documentation on this. Attach it if any.

Comment: have attached it to the message

Comment: I have the mochi bridge component working on my site http://www.bittygame.com.
Are you certain the game you are using has high scores? Not all mochi games do. Also - do you have a score gateway set up? I see you are using "http://example.com/game"
View the source of this page to see what I did.
http://www.bittygame.com/playgame.php?game=28

Answer (score 0):

though its a bit late but I successfully parsed and load data from mochi feeds using C# and ASP.NET. The requested json file is parsed, checks for the game existence if not found then enters the game in database and adds to a queue which is later processed in a thread that downloads game and images. I have created two websites suing my own script like [Gamefiz](http://gamefiz.com) and [Curlgames](http://curlgames.com)